# What's the difference between useCallback and useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Maybe I misunderstood something, but useCallback Hook runs everytime when re-render happens.

I passed inputs - as a second argument to useCallback - non-ever-changeable constants - but returned memoized callback still runs my expensive calculations at every render (I'm pretty sure - you can check by yourself in the snippet below).

I've changed useCallback to useMemo - and useMemo works as expected — runs when passed inputs changes. And really memoizes the expensive calculations.

Live example:

```js
'use strict';

const { useState, useCallback, useMemo } = React;

const neverChange = 'I never change';
const oneSecond = 1000;

function App() {
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(0);
  
  // This  expensive function executes everytime when render happens:
  const calcCallback = useCallback(() => expensiveCalc('useCallback'), [neverChange]);
  const computedCallback = calcCallback();
  
  // This  executes once
  const computedMemo = useMemo(() => expensiveCalc('useMemo'), [neverChange]);
  
  setTimeout(() => setSecond(second + 1), oneSecond);
  
  return `
    useCallback: ${computedCallback} times |
    useMemo: ${computedMemo} |
    App lifetime: ${second}sec.
  `;
}

const tenThousand = 10 * 1000;
let expensiveCalcExecutedTimes = { 'useCallback': 0, 'useMemo': 0 };

function expensiveCalc(hook) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < tenThousand) i++;
  
  return ++expensiveCalcExecutedTimes[hook];
}


ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App),
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```html
<h1>useCallback vs useMemo:</h1>
<div id="app">Loading...</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useMemo` is intended to run the function and return a value at when the component renders (assuming one of the dependancies has changed). `useCallback` is intended to return a (memoized) function at render time, but does not actually call the function yet; typically you just pass this function to an `onClick` parameter or something like that.

You can use them interchangeably if called correctly, for example having `useMemo` return a function is equivalent to `useCallback`, or using `useCallback` and then calling the returned function is similar to `useMemo`

Answer (score 5):

`useMemo()` makes the function run only when inputs change. Else it returns the memoized(cached) result. It is only suggested to use `useMemo()` for functions involving complex calculations(more time complexity) as there is cost in running `useMemo()`

`useCallback()` prevents the new instance of the function(I mean function is redefined) being created on each rerender and thus prevents the rerendering of child components if we pass the function as props to them

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (25.05.2020), `useCallback` and `useMemo` can be used Interchangiably:

```
const fn = () => { function code }

const fn1 = React.useCallback(fn, deps)
const fn2 = React.useMemo(() => fn, deps)
```

In both cases, fn1 and fn2 is saved between different renders.
The difference is that useCallback might be a improved in the future where it always returns the same function and relays it to the last function that is passed to it.

I wrote about it [here](https://medium.com/welldone-software/react-usecallback-invalidates-too-often-in-practice-f398ee61f429?source=friends_link&sk=6a65ee1d0cba187cd3a47ec055802259).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your function `expensiveCalc` in the `useCallback` will be run on every render because you are calling the memoized function directly below the `useCallback` on every render.

`useCallback` will memoize and return the actual function, so even though the function is memoized it will still be run whenever you call it.

In the example, this is essentially what is happening:

```js
const calcCallback = () => expensiveCalc('useCallback');
const computedCallback = calcCallback();
```

**In your case you should not use `useCallback`.**

**If possible** move the expensive function outside of your react component and execute it outside as well.
e.g:

```js
const calcResult = expensiveCalc('useCallback');
function App() {
```

If, for some reason, that is not possible this is where `useMemo` fits in.

`useMemo` will memoize the value that is returned from your function and will persist it between renders until your dependencies change.

This means **if you do not want to run an expensive function on each render and only want the value, then either move it out of the scope of the react component or use `useMemo`**.

For more details and info about the two hooks you can read more on this article: [What is the difference between useMemo and useCallback?](https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/react/what-is-the-difference-between-usememo-and-usecallback/)